# Move an image to and from effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery, effect

I really like the effect of movement of the spaceship when you move your mouse. Does anyone know how can this effect be achieved with jQuery?

Here's the link:
http://spaceexpeditions.xcor.com/

Comment: Try this plugin: http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/

Comment: Not exactly what we were looking, but thanks for your input ;)

Comment: I know it's been answered but this has much better performance and reponsivness: http://codepen.io/mirohristov/pen/qZGWKX

Comment: Miro, thanks for your input. I liked it! Can you post your comment as an `answer` rather than a `comment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple code

```js
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
    var clientX = e.clientX;
    var clientY = e.clientY;
    
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    
    var constWidth = (width / 2) - $("div").width();
    var constHeight = (height / 2) - $("div").height();   
    
    $("div").css({
        left: constWidth + ((constWidth - clientX) / 10),
        top: constHeight + ((constHeight - clientY) / 10)        
    });  
});
```

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}

div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

See better result of example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk0yrhsz/1/)

Comment: Great! Exactly what we were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

To get the to and fro movement increase the margin left by "x" pixels and then decrease by "x" pixels:

```
$(".blue-box")
   .animate({
      "margin-left": "+=200px",
  }).animate({ "margin-left": "-=200px" });
```